# On webViewDidFinishLoad i am getting extra height of content in swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, swift3

```
  EventWebView.frame.size = EventWebView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
  EventWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;    
  var frame = EventWebView.frame;

  frame.size.width = EventTableView.frame.size.width-40;       // Your desired width here.
  frame.size.height = 1;        // Set the height to a small one.

  EventWebView.frame = frame;       // Set webView's Frame, forcing the Layout of its embedded scrollView with current Frame's constraints (Width set above).

        frame.size.height = EventWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;  // Get the corresponding height from the webView's embedded scrollView.
     heightConstraint.constant = frame.size.height
```

**My HTML Content is** "

> > Testing Description for the new created event by Tester. Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester. Testing Description for the new created event by Tester. Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester. Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester. Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester. Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester. Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.Testing Description for the new created event by Tester.
> >
> > \n"

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I was getting width and height of 1000 when I said 200 in constraints. 

In viewDidLoad I had to add the following lines 

   let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200) // CGFloat, Double, Int
       myView.frame = rect

Comment: @Imran please check your auto layout constraint. My issue is in auto layout constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add WebViewDelegate

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

        webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;    // Property available in iOS 5.0 and later
        var frame = webView.frame;

        frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width-20;       // Your desired width here.
        frame.size.height = 1;        // Set the height to a small one.

        webView.frame = frame;       // Set webView's Frame, forcing the Layout of its embedded scrollView with current Frame's constraints (Width set above).

        frame.size.height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;  // Get the corresponding height from the webView's embedded scrollView.

        webView.frame = frame;
        fl = webView.frame.size.height

    }
```

Make sure please check you autolayout constraint also. This method working fine. if your auto layout are not set properly then you can get extra length in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

NSString *contentHeight = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"];

int height = [contentHeight integerValue];

in your webViewDidFinishLoad method. Make sure you set delegate for web view and implement the above delegate methods in your view controller.